# Search is awful - can anything be done?

Tags: discussion, search

I don't like asking questions on Stack Overflow for various reasons, so I make sure to research for preexisting relevant answers.   Recently I posted a question about [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29) faketime.  It got quickly closed as a duplicate.  However, searching "golang faketime" produces two questions about the Go playground.   Searching for "libfaketime" might get a better result haven't tried yet.

BTW, I did get two fantastic comments which were really useful, and my question has been linked to a useful answer.  The comments have lead me to research how Go does system calls, and they will surely be useful to others.

The question though is why was the search not more useful - not only would it have saved my time in asking, but it would surely also have saved effort all round.   Should I just google (I did) better and not use Stack Overflow search? Could a meta question combine results from closed questions, perhaps, or is that simply an extension of search?

Comment: For this specific case, the problem is that "golang" is not really a good keyword for searching compared to using the [tag:go] tag, e.g. [`[go] faketime`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+faketime&searchOn=3) (17 results).

Comment: Cannot comment on their usefulness, but a google search for ``site:stackoverflow.com golang faketime`` turns up quite a few well-voted hits. Not that this is an excuse for the [so] search itself being abysmal, mind...

Comment: The search is useful, just not as much for finding an answer to a question. Your favorite search engine is far better at that, keep using it. The site search is useful for conditional queries with a specific purpose, say "give me unanswered questions for this tag" (so you may more easily find something to answer yourself).

Comment: Thanks all; didn't occur to me to use a tag. And thanks for confirmation that duckduckgo'ing is the best search method.

Comment: I find that the site's search works best if you know very precisely what you're looking for. As in, an actual post you can locate via the exact search terms. This is the opposite of what you need to find an answer to a question you have because you don't know yet what post to search for. This is problematic even if you know you're searching for a post but don't know enough of the precise terms to bring it forth. If you don't use the correct word  (e.g., "search" vs "searching" vs "find") you'd likely miss the post. Add too little concrete details and you're burrowed in results.

Comment: Yes, searching on the site could yield useful results but not as easily as an external engine seems to find things. If I'm searching for a dupe and I don't know which one it is in advance, I tend to use an external search engine because the site one is so bad at giving me what I know I need but don't know the arcane summoning formula for.

Comment: The site search is currently overwhelmed by garbage. Google is far better at sorting through it

Comment: This has been asked many times before.  Why didn't you search for a duplicate first??? Oh ... never mind.